# I'm a beginner to Angular JS - suggest resources and way to proceed learning it

Tags: angularjs

I'm a beginner to Angular JS and I have to learn it as soon as possible. Suggest some useful resources(websites,articles,blogs,forums) that will help me learn AngularJs. Also suggest the way I should proceed to learn it. I am aware that any book, websites  or tutorials will not cover all concepts. Hence please give suggestions on how to cover all basic concepts and then advanced concepts in AngularJS.

Answer (score 2):

I started with the tutorial videos on Egghead.io. They are really good and nice and short. I recommend starting from the beginning.

http://egghead.io/

Answer (score 0):

Theses sites are good to begining, the official : http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00 (official and very good, do in first),
this one (examples) http://tutorialzine.com/2013/08/learn-angularjs-5-examples/ , somes exercices here https://github.com/jmcunningham/AngularJS-Learning
and one (in french) http://www.frangular.com/

(not tested) 
http://www.angularjstutorial.com/